# Why OnTouchEvent() override method of ViewRender is not firing?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Code:
This is my custom GridViewRenderer which contains scrollview control.

```
public class CustomGridViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Grid, Android.Widget.GridView>
{
public override bool OnTouchEvent(global::Android.Views.MotionEvent events)
{
**//This event is not firing**
}
}
```

This is happening in xamarin.android

Answer (score 0):

If you put the Scrollview in a custom GridView, when you touch this custom GridView, the ScrollView will get focus, so your `OnTouchEvent` cannot be executed.

We can set a padding for custom GridView as shown in the following code. For demonstrating the above conclusion, I set the  custom GridView's background color to Green and ScrollView's backgroundColor to Red

```
 <minitormediamanager:CustomGridView Margin="20,35,20,20"  Padding="20" BackgroundColor="Green">
            <ScrollView  HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="Red">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
                    <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
                    <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
                    <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
                    <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
                    <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
                    <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
                    <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
                    <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column." />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
          
        </minitormediamanager:CustomGridView>
```

Here is my `Grid` customRenderer code.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MinitorMediaManager.CustomGridView), typeof(CustomGridViewRenderer))]
namespace MinitorMediaManager.Droid
{
    //  <Xamarin.Forms.Grid, Android.Views.View>
    public class CustomGridViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MinitorMediaManager.CustomGridView, Android.Views.View>
    {

         public CustomGridViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);

        }
    }
}
```

You can see following running GIF. If I scroll or click the ScrollView(Red background), `OnTouchEvent` will not be executed, But If I click the GridView's padding(Green background), `OnTouchEvent` will be executed.

[image]

In the end, if you want to achieve a touch event, it can be done in the child controls, do not add the GirdView Or StackLayout(If you do not have padding)..

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If the answer is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.